# Donut tutorial : Unexpected lighting behavior

Tags: light, normals, normal-map

I am following the Blender Guru donut tutorial and I've ran into an issue. My camera view is diagonal and I have to put two brick walls into the scene. One of them is lighted correctly, but the second one, no matter how I add it, seems to be lighted the wrong way.

[image: The front view of the plane - dark textured rectangle]

[image: The back view of the plane - bright textured rectangle]

What am I doing wrong? [The .zip with the project (.blend file and textures)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/si3i2zmkgw1chnr/donut.zip?dl=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though your wall is looking the wrong way. Have you tried rotating it by 180 degrees?
For future reference, read up on the topic "normals"

Edit:
Ok, I got it now, sorry for the false lead earlier:

You plugged the texture for the brick wall relief directly into the normal port of your shader.
You need to put a "Bump"-Node (Add-> Vector -> Bump) in between, like so:
[image]

Comment: Yes, I have. Face orientation is alright.

Comment: I changed the answer, it should now solve your problem!